# Can not access database and login to my system

Tags: php, database, authentication, dreamweaver

I want to asking if am typing the right script or not on this php file. It was strange action when I using XAMMP as localhost all script are working and also the database can be read by the connect.php but if I am really using localhost from my hosting I can not login to the next page. I really stuck on this case, I was calling my hosting provider but they said everything is working, so now i dont know what is wrong with my script. I really need your help and let me know what a mistake from this code. thank you guys.

connect.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','psignatu_2013','made2013');
mysql_select_db('psignatu_timeline')
?>
```

and for login script are:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["login"])){
    $username = $_POST["BookingCode"];
    $password =($_POST["password"]);
    if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
        $message = "Field Is Empty";

    }else{
        $check_login = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE BookingCode = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($check_login) == 1){
            $run_login = mysql_fetch_array($check_login);
            $user_id = $run_login['id'];

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

            header('location: conversation.php');
        }else{
            $message = "User Name or Password Incorrect";
        }

    }
    echo "<p>Error - $message</p>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error??

Comment: I think so, its seems like i can not access the data base. When I am using XAMMP for localhost everything is works but when i am using my hosting the login page is not working. try to visit http://psignature.com/inbox/client/login.php ( password : fang1234 username: www71w )

Comment: `Error - User Name or Password Incorrect`.

Comment: you get that message? "Error - User Name or Password Incorrect" ? on my screen only Error - on the top

Comment: ya...im getting that message.

Comment: I was check on the other browser and i am not get the message like that, its only error -.

Comment: And the username or password is correct.

Comment: `echo mysql_num_rows($check_login);` and check

Comment: Can you help me to write full code, because i get the same error-,

Comment: Code looks fine. Put `error_reposting("E_ALL);` See if you get any error.

Comment: sorry I really dont know what you mean, I am new in this online system in php. can you help me with some clue

Comment: add this line `<?php error_reporting("E_ALL); ?>` in beginning of your file your file before include.

Answer (score 0):

In localhost it'll work fine because the database is also in localhost, I guess you'll need to enter an IP address of the DB in your connect.php file. Try that.

Comment: am sorry maybe this is funny but i would like to asking where i can get the IP from phpmyadmin? am new on this things honestly hahahaha

Comment: If it's PhpMyAdmin on the server then on the home page of PhpMyAdmin you'll see the IP address. If you dont see it then ask your web hosting company

Comment: Web server: cpsrvd 11.52.0.21
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqli.  this one?

Comment: I doubt thats the IP address so I suggest you call your Host provider and ask them.

Comment: oh yea where i type the ip? on db host?

Answer (score 0):

OK after reading your question let me point out few things

**First of all**

> "It was strange action when I using XAMMP as localhost all script are working and also the database can be read by the connect.php but if I am really using localhost from my hosting I can not login to the next page."

Your hosting database and your local database are two different database. Its like looking for a data where it doesnt exist.

That's why you can loginto your local db but not on server.

**Second:**
I hope you are not using your real this as a username and password for you db. If you are you should think about changing it asap as you don't want to publish you username and password for security purposes.

To get your things working I would suggest you to export sql script from you local db and import in your server by running phpmyadmin. Make sure you have same db, table username and password.

Good luck.